# How Should VSCode Be Configured To Support A Lerna Monorepo?

Tags: javascript, import, visual-studio-code, lerna, monorepo

I have a [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) monorepo containing lots of packages.

I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. Ensure that VSCode provides the correct import suggestions (based on package names, not on relative paths) from one package to another.
2. Ensure that I can 'Open Definition' of one of these imports and be taken to the src of that file.

For 1. I mean that if I am navigating code within package-a and I start to type a function exported by package-b, I get a suggestion that will trigger the adding of an import: `import { example } from 'package-b'.

For 2. I mean that if I alt/click on the name of a function exported by 'package-b' while navigating the file from a different package that has imported it, I am taken to '/packages/namespace/package/b/src/file-that-contains-function.js',

My (lerna) monorepo is structured as standard, for example here is a 'components' package that is published as `@namespace/components`.

```
- packages
    - components
       - package.json
       - node_modules
       - src
         - index.js
         - components
           - Button
             - index.js
             - Button.js
       - es
         - index.js
         - components
           - Button
             - index.js
             - Button.js
```

Note that each component is represented by a directory so that it can contain other components if necessary. In this example, `packages/components/index` exports `Button` as a named export. Files are transpiled to the package's `/es/` directory.

By default, VSCode provides autosuggestions for imports, but it is confused by this structure and, for if a different package in the monorepo needs to use `Button` for example, will autosuggest all of the following import paths:

- `packages/components/src/index.js`
- `packages/components/src/Button/index.js`
- `packages/components/src/Button/Button.js`
- `packages/components/es/index.js`
- `packages/components/es/Button/index.js`
- `packages/components/es/Button/Button.js`

However none of these are the appropriate, because they will be rendered as relative paths from the importing file to the imported file. In this case, the following import is the correct import:

```
import { Button } from '@namespace/components'
```

Adding excludes to the project's `jsconfig.json` has no effect on the suggested paths, and doesn't even remove the suggestions at `/es/*`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/dist/*",
    "**/coverage/*",
    "**/lib/*",
    "**/public/*",
    "**/es/*"
  ]
}
```

Explicitly adding paths using the "compilerOptions" also fails to set up the correct relationship between the files:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@namespace/components/*": [
        "./packages/namespace-components/src/*.js"
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

At present Cmd/Clicking on an import from a different package fails to open anything (no definition is found).

**How should I configure VSCode so that:**

1. **VSCode autosuggests imports from other packages in the monorepo using the namespaced package as the import value.**
2. **Using 'Open Definition' takes me to the src of that file.**

As requested, I have a single babel config in the root:

```
const { extendBabelConfig } = require(`./packages/example/src`)

const config = extendBabelConfig({
  // Allow local .babelrc.js files to be loaded first as overrides
  babelrcRoots: [`packages/*`],
})

module.exports = config
```

Which extends:

```
const presets = [
  [
    `@babel/preset-env`,
    {
      loose: true,
      modules: false,
      useBuiltIns: `entry`,
      shippedProposals: true,
      targets: {
        browsers: [`>0.25%`, `not dead`],
      },
    },
  ],
  [
    `@babel/preset-react`,
    {
      useBuiltIns: true,
      modules: false,
      pragma: `React.createElement`,
    },
  ],
]

const plugins = [
  `@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign`,
  [
    `babel-plugin-styled-components`,
    {
      displayName: true,
    },
  ],
  [
    `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`,
    {
      loose: true,
    },
  ],
  `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`,
  [
    `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`,
    {
      helpers: true,
      regenerator: true,
    },
  ],
]

// By default we build without transpiling modules so that Webpack can perform
// tree shaking. However Jest cannot handle ES6 imports becuase it runs on
// babel, so we need to transpile imports when running with jest.
if (process.env.UNDER_TEST === `1`) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(`Running under test, so transpiling imports`)
  plugins.push(`@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`)
}

const config = {
  presets,
  plugins,
}

module.exports = config
```

Comment: Do you mind to share how do you build your project?

Comment: Do you have a global `jsconfig.json` file or in every `packages/` directory a `jsconfig.json` file?

Comment: @mathayk each package contains a `/src/` directory. Babel transpiles these files into an `/es/` directory, so each package contains both a `/src/` and `/es/` directory. Added this to the question.

Comment: @mathayk I have a single global `jsconfig.json` file.

Comment: thanks for your answers! Can you add your `babel.config.js` file to the question. Which babel version are you using? Do you have one or more babel config file?

Comment: @mathayk added config to the question. 
"@babel/cli": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0-rc.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0-rc.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.56",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.5",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: This is broken with the latest version of VSCode.**

I finally managed to get this working reliably. You need to create a separate `jsconfig.js` for every package in your monorepo, for example:

- `{monorepo root}/packages/some-package/jsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.js"],
  "exclude": ["src/index.js"]
}
```

Note that I've excluded the `src/index.js` file so it doesn't get offered as an import suggestion from within that package.

This setup appears to achieve:

- Intellisense import suggestions from packages instead of using relative paths.
- Go to definition to source of other packages in the monorepo.

VSCode has been pretty flaky of late, but it seems to be working.

Note this is working for a JavaScript-only monorepo (not Typescript).

Comment: OK, so now we need to figure out how to make it work for TypeScript in WSL2 and we're going to be golden.

Answer (score 13):

In your case, I would make use of [lerna](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) in combination with [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/).
When running `yarn install`, all your packages are linked under your `@namespace` in a global `node_modules` folder. With that, you get IntelliSense.

I've set up an example repository here: https://github.com/flolude/stackoverflow-lerna-monorepo-vscode-intellisense

[image: intellisense preview]

You just need to add `"useWorkspaces": "true"` to your `lerna.json`

```
lerna.json

{
  "packages": ["packages/*"],
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "useWorkspaces": "true"
}
```

And the rest is just propper naming:

```
global package.json

{
  "name": "namespace",
  // ...
}
```

```
package.json of your component package

{
  "name": "@namespace/components",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  // ...
}
```

```
package.json of the package that imports the components

{
  "name": "@namespace/components",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
     "@namespace/components":"0.0.0"
  }
  // ...
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
import { Component1 } from '@namespace/components';

// your logic
```

### Automatically Importing from `@namespace`

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to make this work in VSCode with a Javascript Monorepo. But there are some things you can do:

1. Use Typescript ([tutorial](https://medium.com/@caludio/how-to-use-module-path-aliases-in-visual-studio-typescript-and-javascript-e7851df8eeaa), [other tutorial](https://youtu.be/EoqzOEZIzhg))
2. Use [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)
3. Add `import {} from '@namespace/components'` to the top of your file
   [image: add import to file]
4. Use [Auto Import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) Extension
   [image: auto import]

Comment: Thanks. You're halfway there. The 'Open Definition' is definitely working. However the import suggestions still use a relative path, for example open `/packages/website/src/index.js`, remove the import and type 'Comp'. You will see that VSCode offers an import suggestion, however if you select it, the import it adds will be `import { Component1 } from '../../components/src/component1'`, not `import { Component1 } from '@namespace/components'`.

Comment: Alright, no easy answers for this. But I've edited my answer to provide some options

Comment: I am really sorry. I think in your situation I would try to switch to typescript

Comment: No need to apologise. Unfortunately that isn't really feasible. Too much work for our codebase.

Comment: If you set it up once, it isn't really much more work. But I won't judge as I don't have enough insight into your project. I hope I could at least help a bit :)