# Using yarn workspaces, VSCode does not auto suggest imports from different packages

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, yarn-workspaces

This is my setup:

```
packages
  admin
    package.json // Has a dependency to @packages/common
  common
  user
package.json
```

When I'm working in the `admin` package files, I want to have auto imports suggestions for the `common` package. That's not currently working.

Obs: if I manually type the import, it works.

Which tool is responsible to do the auto import? Is it `eslint` or regular VSCode TypeScript intellisense? Not sure exactly where to look for a solution here.

Which configuration should I have in place to achieve this?

I'm also using `eslint` and `eslint-import-resolver-typescript`

---

**UPDATE**

What is weird is that auto import suggestions works for `types` coming from the `common` package, but not for actual variables and constants.

Comment: The problem has been already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870542/how-should-vscode-be-configured-to-support-a-lerna-monorepo/64773003#64773003)